# Script in cron cannot find command

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, cron, openstack

I have a script which dumps out database and uploads the SQL file to Swift. I've run into the issue where the script runs fine in terminal but fails in cron.

A bit of debugging and I found that the `/usr/local/bin/swift` command is not found in the script.

Here's my crontab entry:

```
*/2 * * * * . /etc/profile; bash /var/lib/postgresql/scripts/backup
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using full path to `swift` as `/usr/local/bin/swift`
2. Executing the `/etc/profile` script before executing the bash script.

How do I solve this?

Comment: what is the reason of failure in cron?

Comment: @Luv33preet I have logged `which swift` and that returns empty. Beyond that, `$?` returns `1`. Am I missing something?

Comment: if your script requires root permissions, better add the cronjob in `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @Luv33preet would it cause any issues? the script needs to be run under `postgres` user.

Comment: check this if it helps, https://askubuntu.com/questions/907421/cronjob-different-behaviours

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cron doesn't run with the same environment as a user.  If you do the following you will see what I mean:

type `env` from your terminal prompt and make note of the output.

Then set a cron job like this and compare it's output to the previous:

```
*/5 * * * * env > ~/output.txt
```

You will find that the issue is likely because `crontab` does not have the same `PATH` variable as your user.  As a solution to this you can (from your postgres user) `echo $PATH` and then copy the results of that to the first line of your crontab (something like this)

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/jbutryn/.local/bin:/home/jbutryn/bin
```

Or if you want to be more specific you can simply add the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

However I normally always put my user's PATH in crontab because I haven't yet heard a good reason not to do so and you will likely run into this issue again if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You made one of the most common [cron mistakes](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/top-4-cron-mistakes.html).
If you using specific environment add path to $PATH:

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/script
export PATH
```

Also check your cron log (/var/log/cron or /var/log/syslog).
And check user's permission for binary files.